# Simple change results in make: Error 1

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

Had this:

```
rtable.insert ( pair<string,string>(destination,nhop) ); // route insertion
return 0;
```

Changed it to this:

```
if (rtable.insert ( pair<string,string>(destination,nhop)) == 0){
    return 0;
}
```

First one compiles fine. Second one gives me a make error 1. I can go back and forth all day -- I can't see any issues. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That overload of `std::map::insert()` returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`.  You can't compare that against zero.

That `bool` element tells you whether a new element was inserted; if you want to compare against that you can simply use:

```
if (rtable.insert(pair<string,string>(destination,nhop)).second)
    return 0
```

Comment: I read the documentation wrong for the return of the command. Should have looked at it more carefully. Thanks.